# Java combine images one on top of the other

Tags: java, image, graphics

I want to create one image from 2 images so the first one will be above the second one:

```
----------------
image1
----------------
----------------
image2
----------------
```

So the output image will have have the height and width of image 1 + image 2:

Here is my code:

```
private void combainImages(List<String> imageList, String combainedImages)
            throws IOException {
        //paths for the images
        String aPath = imageList.get(0);
        String bPath = imageList.get(1);
        //as image
        BufferedImage a = ImageIO.read(new File(aPath));
        BufferedImage b = ImageIO.read(new File(bPath));

        int aw = a.getWidth(); //551
        int ah = a.getHeight(); //600

        int bw = b.getWidth(); //551
        int bh = b.getHeight(); //600

        BufferedImage c = new BufferedImage(a.getHeight() + b.getHeight(),
                a.getWidth() + b.getWidth(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        // 1200 1102
        Graphics g = c.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(a, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(b, 0, a.getWidth(), null);
        ImageIO.write(c, "PNG", new File(combainedImages));
    }
```

The output for this is a big space between the 2 image.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're choosing the Y position based on the width rather than the height.

```
g.drawImage(b, 0, a.getWidth(), null);
```

should be

```
g.drawImage(b, 0, a.getHeight(), null);
```

Comment: Oh, and what Dan said.